# How can I add code to a numeric list's item without breaking the numbering?

Tags: markdown, bitbucket, wiki

I'm trying to add code to a numeric list in Markdown (in the wiki of a BitBucket repository), but it break the numbering of the list: in the example below, item 3 starts with a 1.

````
1. item one

    text

2. item two

    text

```
#!ini
     code
```

3. item 3
````

[image]

Comment: I don't know how it works on Bitbucket, but on SO you can add code in a list by indenting it further. 8 spaces instead of 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the backticks and simply indent your code by 4*(n+1) spaces, where n is the nesting level. In this case, the nesting level is 1, so you have to indent your code by 8 spaces.

```
1. item one

    text

2. item two

    text

        #!ini
        code

3. item 3
```

#### Test in the wiki of a BitBucket repo

The output is as desired:

[image]